# Use MongoDB to find out maximum marks in each exam

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate

I have the following json data:

```
{ "_id" : { "Soid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c36a" }, "student_id" : 4, "class_id" : 5, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 5.466727688497352 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 48.70365097712529 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 84.00121183981668 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 67.53163246780703 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 66.19091789853015 } ] },
{ "_id" : { "Soid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c354" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 7, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 18.20492211025179 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 60.4769945611789 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 75.62999921143397 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 72.41228797373115 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 74.06744381708968 } ] },
{ "_id" : { "Soid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c358" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 10, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 30.93065784731665 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 55.98003281528393 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 55.6752702814148 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 63.15391302252755 } ] },
```

and I want to find out the maximum marks obtaind in each exam type so "exam", "quiz" and "homework".

I know I can use mongos aggregate() and I know how to get a maximum like this:

```
 db.grades.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "Soid",
          {$scores: maxQuantity: { $max: "$score" }}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

But how do I get to the nested parts and determine the maximum there? I tried to use the unwind function, but I dont know the excact syntax.

Comment: You can find the maximum score first and compare that score with each item. Or you can create an array and use `$reduce` on it. But your current code doesn't seem to be valid, there is no `$scores` operator and the object in `$group` is not a valid javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    db.grades.aggregate([
      {$unwind: "$scores" },
      {$group: { _id: "$scores.type", maxQuantity: { $max: "$scores.score" } }},
])
```

You first `$unwind` the scores so you have a record for every array element in every document. Then you can group it by type. 
So the response would be like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "homework",
    "maxQuantity" : 84.0012118398167
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "quiz",
    "maxQuantity" : 60.4769945611789
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "exam",
    "maxQuantity" : 30.9306578473166
}
```